# Matching records that fall into same date range

Tags: sql-server

I've a sales table with multiple prices for the same product. Each with a range for when that price is active. `From` and a `To`. I need to find if they are any `Prices` that overlap for the same `product`

```
 Select Id ,Geo, productId, [From], [To] 
 from   [Store_Pricing].[dbo].[SalesPrice] SP
 Where  Id IN (
                Select SP1.Id 
                from (
                        Select Id 
                        from [Store_Pricing].[dbo].[SalesPrice] 
                        Where SP.Id != Id AND [From] <= SP.[From] AND ISNULL([To], GETUTCDATE()) >= ISNULL(SP.[To], GETUTCDATE()) AND IsDeprecated = 0
                     ) SP1
            ) 
        AND productId = '1554A9A6-4CA6-3A3C-BDCB-000020012A41'
```

So the `SP.Id != Id` prevents any records being returned. I'm not sure i'm doing it fully correct. if i remove `SP.Id != Id` all records get returned. Which i'm assuming is because it the same record is being compared

Comment: Sample data and expected output would really help here

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT /* DISTINCT */ *
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE t1.product = t2.product
  AND t1.from < t2.till
  AND t2.from < t1.till
```

If adjacent intervals must be returned use `<=` (safe compare) instead of `<` (strong compare).